# How did medieval architects determine sizes and numbers of pillars, buttresses etc?

Tags: middle-ages, construction

While looking at some magnificent gothic cathedrals, I began to wonder how these buildings were designed. (I hope that this site it the right place to ask, rather than the engineering one?)

For example, consider the period from, say, 1130 to 1300, where the gothic style of architecture developed (but my question applies to other periods as well). A number of new large cathedrals were constructed, each with some new elements compared to the previous ones (pointy arches, rib vaults, flying buttresses) and generally becoming taller.

How did the architects (or civil engineers or whatever is the term for the people designing these buildings) determine the appropriate parameters of all these elements? By this I mean, e.g., pillar sizes, number, size and position of flying buttresses, vault spans etc?

- I presume that there was no machinery available to calculate these values. Or was there?
- I would guess that for smaller or more common buildings, there is a lot of experience and empirical knowledge. However, for the large early gothic cathedrals, there could not have been much experience, at least on that scale.
- Or were there examples of collapses (or near-collapses) that showed the design boundaries?
- Are there records of experiments, i.e., buildings made primarily to test e.g. vault spans or somesuch?
- Were most things just overengineered?
- Cathedral construction took decades. Did they update designs in the meantime *for reasons of stability*?

So how did they do it?

Comment: Yes, some collapsed (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauvais_Cathedral). Various cathedrals had work done to reinforce areas that were showing issues.

Comment: @JonCuster Ah that's interesting! So there they had too high a vault with too small buttresses, and from the Wikipedia page it seems they intentionally pushed the design parameters. Do we know how the architects arrived at their design (or sold it to the bishop), or how it was received and considered in the construction of other cathedrals at the time?

Comment: They sold it by promising it would be higher, just what the main donors wanted. Nothing was 'overengineered' because that would imply that engineering disciplines in the modern sense had been developed. They were built by craftsmen, many of whom moved from project to project over their life, even as each project lasted a lifetime or more. Lots of trial and error, rules of thumb, etc.

Comment: @JonCuster But, closet to the core of the question: Since construction took so long, there must have been plans (in one way or other) at the "construction office" (not just in the head of the chief builder) which would presumably include the entire building (?), or at least significant parts of it (say choir, transept, nave, west facade with towers). So from the outset, someone must have decided on height and buttresses. I guess those people did work on other large cathedral or similar projects projects. Do these plans (or maybe contracts) survive, and/or any contemporary annotations/remarks?

Comment: Most cathedrals of Europe have a associated [Bauhütte](https://ich.unesco.org/en/BSP/craft-techniques-and-customary-practices-of-cathedral-workshops-or-bauhutten-in-europe-know-how-transmission-development-of-knowledge-and-innovation-01558), an office and workshop that organizes the neccessary work on the building since its first planing stage. These "mason's loges", lead by a "Baumeister" (_magister fabricae ecclesiae_, master builder of the church) continue to exist until today and own all the plans ever drafted for the cathedral (provided they did not get lost in some disaster)...

Comment: ...One of many examples: this [plan of the western front of the Cologne catherdral](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fassadenplan_F_vom_Kölner_Dom.jpg), drawn in 1370 probably by [Master Michael](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meister_Michael_(Dombaumeister)).

Comment: @Toffomat: While perhaps true in specific cases, categorically false in general; consider the case of Florence's *il Duomo*: "The cathedral was begun in 1296; during the 14th century the nave was completed and work commenced on the complex octagon of the east end. By 1418 construction had reached the stage at which the technical problems of constructing a vault above the enormous dimensions of the octagon had to be solved. These problems had involved previous generations of cathedral architects in bitter disputes. ..."

Comment: "... It was Brunelleschi who worked out a successful method to vault the dome, invented the machinery necessary to carry it out, and designed the structure’s crowning lantern and its lateral tribunes (semicircular structures). He was named chief architect (capomaestro) of the dome project in 1420 and remained in that office until his death in 1446" Note that agreement on how the dome was to be designed and constructed didn't even begin until over a century ***after*** construction on the cathedral commenced. [Link](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Filippo-Brunelleschi)

Comment: @ccprog Oh right, I've seen (parts of a copy?) of that plan once. Are there plans where the executing (e.g.) masons can read off wall thicknesses and other more technical info?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Interesting! Did they know in 1296 that they did not have a working design? Or did they have a design that turned out not to work? And how did they determine that?

Comment: @Toffomat: They had no idea in 1296 how the dome they envisioned - significantly larger than any other ever built - would be constructed.  Brunelleschi made no written plans of how it would be built, and so obscured the construction site from both external and internal view that even his workers had no overall comprehension of how it was being built with no scaffolding. Only a couple of years ago was his technique rediscovered through some serious scientific archaeologic investigation and careful measurement made between the domes. [Florence's Dome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD3fJphus-o)

Comment: [Construction secrets of Brunelleschi 's dome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVwN1b6-5QU)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Aso, are there records of the "bitter disputes" of "previous generations of cathedral architects"? These would probably show they design methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How did medieval architects determine sizes and numbers of pillars, buttresses etc?

Mostly, by use of scale models, chalk floor drawings, and elaborate simulations of beam loading constructed by hanging weights from string (as with [Gaudi's Hanging Chain Models](http://dataphys.org/list/gaudis-hanging-chain-models/)).

"But where are the plans?" you ask.

The rectangular-grid mathematics on which such are based, analytic geometry, didn't yet exist; it's a contrivance of Rene Descartes (hence Cartesian plane) only developed in the 16th century. The printing processes (and presses) for mass reproduction blueprints or anything similar, and distributing them to workmen, likewise are centuries in the future. It's been proposed that the master masons appointed as architects constructed templates for the workmen in their tracing rooms, as that is how restoration is now done; but that is contested by [Holton](https://www.arct.cam.ac.uk/Downloads/ichs/vol-2-1579-1598-holton.pdf) as the two surviving *tracing rooms* York Minster and Wells have no access large enough for the necessary templates to be transported out.

Consider the example of Cupola Firenze - the Dome of Florence, constructed by [Brunelleschi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filippo_Brunelleschi) overtop [Cathedral of Saint Mary of the Flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Cathedral). Conceived to be topped by the largest dome ever yet conceived, construction was begun in 1296 A.D. and "completed" in 1380; but with a 44m, or 150 foot, hole in the roof where the conceived dome was to have been.

"Yes - let's build a cathedral, seating 30,000 and (to be) topped by the world's largest dome; and leave a 180 foot diameter hole where the dome should be, for a generation, until our great grand children figure out how to construct it."

A design contest for the dome, announced in 1418, was won by Brunelleschi with a scale model of the to-be-completed dome with its lantern. But Brunelleschi refused to share either his design or means of construction without any scaffolding ("without either dirt or coins", referring to the legendary means by which the dome of the Pantheon had been constructed).

Unwilling to entrust the entire construction to a single mere goldsmith, construction was awarded jointly to Brunelleschi and his rival Ghibert. Construction began in 1420; but by 1423 Ghibert admitted that the it was beyond his comprehension and Brunelleschi was given sole authority.

The dome construction was made self-supporting by means of a clever six-fold spiral herringbone over the octagonal base. This design pattern then reappears elsewhere, despite Brunelleschi's draping of cloths over and around the construction site to maintain secrecy, so his better workmen recognized this innovation. However, his true masterpiece was in how he ensured the six octagonal walls would - and did - meet cleanly at the apex to support the lantern.

The trick of how he did that, with strings stretched out from a well obscured workspace beneath the center of the dome, was only rediscovered a few years ago by some clever scientific archaeology.

---

Update, from comments below:

- Q: Did the Florentinians lack the entire dome design or "just" the method of construction?
- A: The Florentines held a ***design*** contest in 1418-19, for completion of the basilica; won by Brunelleschi. The only (apparent) constraints were the (already built) octagonal footprint for the dome, and the thickness/strength of the (again, already built) walls supporting that footprint. Some commentary I read seem to imply that the supporting wall thickness was less than ideal for the size of dome envisaged (and thus possibly complicating and delaying the design and construction); but that's just a bit of *reading between the lines* and not official.
- Q's: ... how did [medieval master masons] estimate the correct weight [in their string-and-weight load simulations)? Did the architects consider different densities and strengths of brick/Sandstone/Granite etc?
- A: I have not researched that. In truth, that should be a separate question I think; or, at least, a full separate answer.

---

[Translation of the Design Contest announcement](https://youtu.be/rngQFItcwJ4?t=2795):

[image]

[Modern analysis of ??? *herring-bone* brickwork in the dome](https://youtu.be/rngQFItcwJ4?t=3459)

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the museum attached to Gaudi's Sagreda Familia in Barcelona, one of Gaudi's design models survives and is exhibited. It's a structure about 6' high of beams and little sacks full of weights which, together, formed an analog model of the finished basilica. This was done around the turn of the last century, but there is nothing at all in this that could not have been done (and probably was done) 800 years earlier.  See http://dataphys.org/list/gaudis-hanging-chain-models/

Comment: @MarkOlson: Yes, this is exactly how they simulated beam loading. May I add the link, comments being ephemeral and all that?

Comment: Please feel free!

Comment: Oh that is pretty cool! So if I understand correctly: The strings are used to produce the correct (inverted) vault shape,and the weights represent external loads (other vault ribs etc.)? So how did they estimate the correct weight? And: Did the Florentinians lack the entire dome design or "just" the method of construction? Finally: Did the architects consider different densities and strengths of brick/Sandstone/Granite etc?

Comment: @Toffomat: The Florentines held a ***design*** contest in 1418-19, for completion of the basilica; won by Brunelleschi. The only (apparent) constraints were the (already built) octagonal footprint for the dome, and the thickness/strength of the (again, already built) walls supporting that footprint. Some commentary I read seem to imply that the supporting wall thickness was less than ideal for the size of dome envisaged (and thus possibly complicating and delaying the design and construction); but that's just a bit of *reading between the lines* and not official.